# Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Android Kotlin

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to implement Azure Aactive Directry B2C in my Andodid Kotlin app, I have followed this [medium](https://medium.com/neudesic-innovation/using-azure-ad-b2c-to-authenticate-android-app-users-9506f7a01a17) article.

The following is my *MainActivity.kt*

package com.example.azureactive

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationCallback
import com.microsoft.identity.client.IAccount
import com.microsoft.identity.client.IAuthenticationResult
import com.microsoft.identity.client.IPublicClientApplication
import com.microsoft.identity.client.ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication
import com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalException
import com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var msalApplication: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication? = null
private var account: IAccount? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val logInButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.logInButton)
    logInButton.setOnClickListener {
        logIn()
    }
    logInButton.isEnabled = false



    try {
        PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
            this,
            R.raw.auth_config_b2c,
            object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {

                override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication?) {
                    println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
                    msalApplication = application
                    logInButton.isEnabled = true
                }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
                    print(exception!!)
                }
            })
    } catch (error: Error) {
        println(error)
    }
}


private fun logIn() {
    val scopes =
        arrayOf("https://icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com/api/api.read")
    msalApplication!!.signIn(
        this,
        null,
        scopes,
        object : AuthenticationCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult?) {
                account = authenticationResult!!.account
            }

            override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
                print(exception!!)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                print("Cancelled")
            }
        })
}
}
```

And this is my *auth_config_b2c.json*

```
{
  "client_id" : "17e28ea9-2377-4493-9e07-f414a00f68fa",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidkotlinapp/iUQmP3LPooa86d5yfBCs5QEsSEQ%3D",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "https://icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.b2clogin.com/icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susi/",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "https://icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.b2clogin.com/icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_reset_password/"
    },
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "https://icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.b2clogin.com/icaniocom.onmicrosoft.com.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_edit_profile/"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.azureactive"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AzureActive"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
            android:exported="true"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="/com.azuresamples.msalandroidkotlinapp"
                    android:path="/iUQmP3LPooa86d5yfBCs5QEsSEQ="
                    android:scheme="msauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

And this is my *build.gradle.kts(Module:app)*

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.azureactive"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.azureactive"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    implementation("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:4.7.0") {
        exclude(group = "com.microsoft.device.display")
    }
}
```

I get these errors

```
2023-09-12 18:50:53.689 15787-15787 FBI                     com.example.azureactive              E  Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libmagtsync.so" not found
2023-09-12 18:50:53.722 15787-15836 ion                     com.example.azureactive              E  ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

The Button Login Button stays disabled, And [here](https://github.com/joe-icanio/azure-ad-b2c-auth-setup) is my git repo containing all the code

Comment: Do not exclude group in the implementation and try.